# How to run Appium scripts in multiple devices in Eclipse?

Tags: appium, ui-automation

Is there any chance on running scripts in multiple devices in Eclipse to run Appium scripts?

Currently I am able to run the scripts only on device.
So I need to run the scripts in multiple devices.
Please help me to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please use 'google' for this.. Learn a bit about Selenium-Grid.

Also look for 'appium parallel execution' (https://discuss.appium.io/t/appium-parallel-execution-grid/4375/80)

Comment: Yeah I will and Thank You so much

Answer (score 0):

Check for Appium.
You have to run multiple Appium serves on different ports and attach device to it

```
$ appium -p 4723 -U deviceName1
$ appium -p 4725 -U deviceName2
```

Then you can write test script in Eclipse using selenium.

Here is an article which discusses how to Automate UI testing for multiple devices. Also provides implementation details.[How I automated testing for an app spanning interactions between multiple devices](https://medium.com/@charianand.maurya/how-i-automated-testing-for-an-app-spanning-interactions-between-multiple-devices-5cf3ca9df8d0)